# posting error in github page (build error)

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, chirpy

```
  *  744:1453: ERROR: Start tag of nonvoid HTML element ends with '/>', use '>'.
```

```
> `HTML-Proofer found 42 failures!
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`
```

I want to post my .ipynb file on my blog, so I downloaded the .ipynb file as a .md file in Jupyter notebook.

When I put the .md file in the _posts folder and checked the blog through jekyll serve (using jekyll-theme-chirpy), it worked fine.

But when I tried to post that .md file to my GitHub blog,
there was an error (above) in GitHub actions that I can't understand.

how can I solve this problem?

I did:

- theme upgrade
- I tried some things in window and mac both
- I wrote the front matter in a .md file

Comment: Today I learned "An IPYNB file is a notebook document created by Jupyter Notebook". Welcome to Stackoverflow, Locally the file works fine but not on GitHub? Can you share the post/layout code or the repo plus the actions log, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you HTML code. [https://rocketvalidator.com](https://rocketvalidator.com/html-validation/self-closing-syntax-used-on-a-non-void-html-element-ignoring-the-slash-and-treating-as-a-start-tag) explains the message

*Self-closing syntax (“/>”) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.*

> A slash character (/), normally used for self-closing tags, has been found in an unexpected place for a tag, and the validator has decided to ignore it and treat is as a start tag instead.

The page also lists possible options and potential mistakes (check the link on top for the examples I left out here):

> HTML tags can go in pairs (start tag, end tag) or be self-closing.
>
> In HTML5, the ending slash and the preceding space is optional for self-closing tags so all of these are valid.
>
> A common mistake is including a slash tag on a start tag, as in the following example. If the Nu HTML checker encounters that, it will ignore the slash and just treat the tag as a start tag.